# ¿Como obtener el Array contenido dentro de otro Array en Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

Estoy tratando de enviar datos a traves de @Input a un componente en Angular.

Tengo el servicio que maneja los datos y retorna un arreglo multidimensional que contiene un array de tipo **string** y otro de tipo **number**

```
  getEmployeeSales(from:string,to:string):any[]{
    let result: any[] = []
    this.DataLavu.getRangeData('orders','closed',from,to, (responseFromLavu)=>{
      let resp : DataOrdersLavu = responseFromLavu
      let empleados: string[] = []
      let ventaEmpleados: number[] = []

      resp.results.row.forEach(x => {
        if(!empleados.includes(x.server)){
          empleados.push(x.server)
          ventaEmpleados.push(0)
        }
        ventaEmpleados[empleados.indexOf(x.server)]+=Number(x.subtotal)
      })
      result.push(empleados)
      result.push(ventaEmpleados)
    });
    return result
  }
```

Hice la prueba desde mi componente padre para verificar el contenido del array:

```
export class RankingSalesComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public commonComponentsHeaderService: CommonComponentsHeaderService, private data:ProcessDataService) {
    commonComponentsHeaderService.setTitles("Ranking de ventas","Por empleado");
    commonComponentsHeaderService.setBreadCrum({
        level1: {text:"Ranking de ventas", route:"ranking-sales",params:[],active:true},
      }
    )}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(this.data.getEmployeeSales('2022-08-15','2022-08-16'))
  }

}
```

Y hasta ahí todo bien, me muestra el array con los dos arrays dentro de él
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema está cuando trato de obtener uno de los dos arrays de la siguiente forma, ya que me lo muestra con *undefined*

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(this.data.getEmployeeSales('2022-08-15','2022-08-16')[0])
  }
```

¿Cual es el problema y cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: Bueno, el tema del problema está en la función de tu servicio, el getRangeData(), quizá tengas que revisar tu backend, verificaste si te está trayendo los datos desde el controlador ? me refiero a simular la data de entrada (parámetros) y traer la respueta 'en crudo'

Comment: @Isanchezo esa parte funciona bien, la respuesta que me da la API es correcta, el problema está con el ultimo arreglo del cual no puedo sacar los otros dos arreglos que se encuentran dentro de él, lo cual me parece muy extraño